# Catching Enter Keypress from a CComboBox

Tags: mfc, keypress, ccombobox

Once a user types something in to my CComboBox (within a CDialog subclass) and presses Enter, I would like to add what they've written to the list of options, and do some other handling. How do you do that in MFC?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/combobox_tut.aspx) is some information you might find useful:

> The `ENTER` key, by default, is only
>   processed by the combo box when the
>   drop list is open, and in this case it
>   has the same effect as a mouse click
>   and makes the selection. A **Simple**
>   combo box does not process the `ENTER`
>   key at all and is passed to the parent
>   dialog. If you wish to handle the
>   `ENTER` key in any other way the combo
>   box will need to be subclassed and
>   handler written for the purpose. You
>   may like to check out [Implementing an
>   autocompleting Combobox - By Chris
>   Maunder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/combocompletion.aspx) as a starting point to which
>   the handler can be added.